# Android secuirty my App get serial number to device

Tags: java, android, security, android-studio, serial-number

in my app : I want to prevent  user send my app to another phone 
i have idea to check serial number to device  and every user i sell my app for him
,i will give him app open on his device with his derail number just 
don't open in another phone

MY question is How i can check the Serial number to device  ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Comment: i will store all  sn to device i sell him 
if I see duplicate i will give him another phone 
@Charles